# Do cache queries work on relation fields and global sets?

Tags: cache, query, elementquery

I see in the docs I can do something like:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries
  .sectionId(2)
  .with(['someRelationField'])
  .cache(0)
  .all() 
%}
```

and this will cache the query indefinitely because of `.cache(0)`.

What if I would like to cache some matrix blocks in a global set? For example:

```
{% set blocks = myGlobalSet
  .myMatrixField
  .with(['someRelationField'])
  .cache(0)
  .all() 
%}
```

Would that cache that query like I believe it will or, since it's a relation to the global set, will it mess with the query is some way?

Answer (score 2):

`.cache()` is a rather low-level method defined in `yii\db\Command`, that sets class-level cache duration and dependency properties:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/5406e5dad3eaa4e9d58f65bb565d37adc4307f3b/framework/db/Command.php#L117-L130

Although [Craft registers an `ElementQueryTagDependency`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/element-queries.html#caching-element-queries) for you by default, the cache properties know nothing about Craft and are subsequently used internally in the `Command::queryInternal` method to cache the result of an executed query:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/5406e5dad3eaa4e9d58f65bb565d37adc4307f3b/framework/db/Command.php#L1186-L1189

So, the answer to your question is that the query result will be cached as expected – the caching mechanism knows nothing of relations to global sets and so doesn’t discriminate.